# SharePoint Server 2019: All Site contents was loaded by https while site is binding to http

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, https, customization

I installed SharePoint server 2019, created a new web app and site using http protocol.

I deployed some custom code which include css, js and c# through wsp file.

But when I access the site from browser, it shows blank page. I checked in network tab, all content files are loading by https instead of http:

[image: error screenshot]

What should I do to fix this error?